# My bash does not recognize tmuxinator command

Tags: rubygems, cygwin, tmux, tmuxinator

I have installed tmuxinator in to cygwin using [following](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator) instruction. And ruby like [there](https://gist.github.com/aspyatkin/d2b28fc754e009bd4a48). The whole installation was successful, but if I run `tmuxinator` I get following error:

```
╔═xakep ▷ DESKTOP-FOIFIIK:[~]:
╚> gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

builder (3.2.3)
did_you_mean (1.0.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
minitest (5.10.3)
psych (2.2.4)
rake (12.1.0)
rdoc (5.1.0)
thor (0.20.0)
tmuxinator (0.12.0)
xdg (2.2.3)
╔═xakep ▷ DESKTOP-FOIFIIK:[~]:
╚> tmuxinator
-bash: tmuxinator: command not found
```

**UPDATE**

I didn't found tmuxinator in my path, but I don't know which path I schould add to it.

Its all running in my cygwin and I checked some staff and versions:

```
╔═xakep ▷ DESKTOP-FOIFIIK:[~]:
╚> echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
╔═xakep ▷ DESKTOP-FOIFIIK:[~]:
╚> echo $EDITOR
vim
╔═xakep ▷ DESKTOP-FOIFIIK:[~]:
╚> ruby -v
ruby 2.3.6p384 (2017-12-14 revision 9808) [x86_64-cygwin]
last_commit=ruby 2.3.3
╔═xakep ▷ DESKTOP-FOIFIIK:[~]:
╚> tmux -V
tmux 2.6
╔═xakep ▷ DESKTOP-FOIFIIK:[~]:
╚> gem --version
2.6.13
```

And I tried to run another gems that was in my `gem list` outputt, there is what I got:

```
╔═xakep ▷ DESKTOP-FOIFIIK:[~]:
╚> psych
-bash: psych: command not found
╔═xakep ▷ DESKTOP-FOIFIIK:[~]:
╚> builder
-bash: builder: command not found
╔═xakep ▷ DESKTOP-FOIFIIK:[~]:
╚> erubis
-bash: erubis: command not found
╔═xakep ▷ DESKTOP-FOIFIIK:[~]:
╚> did_you_mean
-bash: did_you_mean: command not found
╔═xakep ▷ DESKTOP-FOIFIIK:[~]:
╚> rake
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-12.1.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
╔═xakep ▷ DESKTOP-FOIFIIK:[~]:
╚> rdoc
uh-oh! RDoc had a problem:
cannot load such file -- io/console/size

run with --debug for full backtrace
╔═xakep ▷ DESKTOP-FOIFIIK:[~]:
╚> thor
-bash: thor: command not found
╔═xakep ▷ DESKTOP-FOIFIIK:[~]:
╚> xdg
-bash: xdg: command not found
```

It seems like my shell recognize only `rake` and `rdoc`

Comment: The proper way to install ruby is use the cygwin setup. About the first instruction, have you sourced the `tmuxinator.bash` ?

Comment: Yes and I added it after source in to my .bashrc file

Comment: So where was tmuxinator installed and is that directory in your PATH?

Comment: I don't think that is in my path, Im can check it tomorrow. Which folder must be added to path? I added rbenv to my path but not tmuxinator

Comment: Are you expecting we look for you inside the `tmuxinator.bash` to find the problem ? This is not the scope of `stackoverflow`

Answer (score 0):

I created a folder `.bin` in my home directory, I copied the file [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/tree/master/bin) there.
And fixed it by adding `/home/xakep/.bin` in to my `$PATH` Thx @varro

```
╔═xakep ▷ khashashin:[~]:
╚> export PATH=$PATH:/home/xakep/.bin
```

It works now!

```
╔═xakep ▷ khashashin:[~]:
╚> tmuxinator
tmuxinator commands:
  tmuxinator commands                          # Lists commands available in tmuxinator
  tmuxinator completions [arg1 arg2]           # Used for shell completion
  tmuxinator copy [EXISTING] [NEW]             # Copy an existing project to a new project and open it in your editor
  tmuxinator debug [PROJECT] [ARGS]            # Output the shell commands that are generated by tmuxinator
  tmuxinator delete [PROJECT1] [PROJECT2] ...  # Deletes given project
  tmuxinator doctor                            # Look for problems in your configuration
  tmuxinator help [COMMAND]                    # Describe available commands or one specific command
  tmuxinator implode                           # Deletes all tmuxinator projects
  tmuxinator list                              # Lists all tmuxinator projects
  tmuxinator local                             # Start a tmux session using ./.tmuxinator.yml
  tmuxinator new [PROJECT] [SESSION]           # Create a new project file and open it in your editor
  tmuxinator start [PROJECT] [ARGS]            # Start a tmux session using a project's name (with an optional [ALIAS] for project reuse) or a path to a project config file (via the -p flag)
  tmuxinator stop [PROJECT]                    # Stop a tmux session using a project's tmuxinator config
  tmuxinator version                           # Display installed tmuxinator version
```

Comment: Note that the canonical place to store your private executables is `~/bin`, not `~/.bin`.  (There's no reason to make `~/bin` a dot-file.)